# updating arraylist with condition

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class with main method. the method `addStudents()` simply adds student to the students arraylist. but this method adds null values on rollnumber property.

the another method `addRollNumber()` should add roll numbers on the students arraylist in such a way that if idNumber of student to be added already exists in the students arraylist their roll numbers should be same.

like in this case two students maria and smriti have same idNumber i.e 145. now the updated arraylist should have same rollNumber for both. how can i achieve this ?

```
public class RollNoGenerator {


    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Student> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RollNoGenerator rollNoGenerator = new RollNoGenerator();
        rollNoGenerator.addStudents();
        rollNoGenerator.addRollNumber();
        rollNoGenerator.pritnList();  
    }

   //this method currently is not producing the required output
    public void addRollNumber() {

        Iterator itr = students.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Student std = (Student) itr.next();
            if(newList.contains(std.getIdNumber())) {
                std.setRollNumber("1");
                newList.add(std);


            }else {
                newList.add(std);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addStudents() {
        Student student = new Student("bob","123","new york","red",null);
        Student student1 = new Student("ben","125","london","blue",null);
        Student student2 = new Student("maria","145","brisbane","pink",null);
        Student student3 = new Student("smriti","145","portland","brinjal",null);
        students.add(student);
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);

    }


    public void pritnList() {
        for(Student s : newList) {
            System.out.println(s.getName());
            System.out.println(s.getRollNumber());
        }
    }

}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String idNumber;
    private String address;
    private String dressColor;
    private String rollNumber;




    public Student() {

    }
    public Student(String name, String idNumber, String address, String 
    dressColor, String rollNumber) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.address = address;
        this.dressColor = dressColor;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

           //getter setters ...............//
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the *same* rollNumber for all? Or, do you want this to be auto-incrementing?

Comment: it is my requirement.

Comment: i  want same roll number for those who have same idNumber.

Comment: And what about the rest? 1,2,3.. and so on?

Comment: yes rest should be incremental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `rollNumber` counter to your class

```
private int nextRollNumber = 1;
```

Then modify your `addRollNumber` method this way (See inline comments)

```
public void addRollNumber() {

  Iterator itr = students.iterator();

  Map<String, String> IdRollNumberPairs = new HashMap<>();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Student std = (Student) itr.next();

    // Look for an other student with the same idNumber in the list
    String rollNumber = IdRollNumberPairs.get(std.getIdNumber());

    // if there is one, copy his rollNumber
    if(rollNumber != null) {
      std.setRollNumber(rollNumber);

    // if not then pick a new roll number
    } else {
      std.setRollNumber(String.valueOf(nextRollNumber));
      IdRollNumberPairs.put(std.getIdNumber(), std.getRollNumber());
      nextRollNumber++;
    }

    // Add student to the list
    newList.add(std);
  }
}
```

Prints out:

```
bob
1
ben
2
maria
3
smriti
3
```

Comment: is there no way to do this without using lamda expression ? because i need to work on java 7.

Comment: Sure, I will modify

Comment: @sagar Here you go :)

Comment: let me check if it works out. i will upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: If you have a really huge number of students, there are ways to optimise it by storing each `idNumber/rollNumber` pairs in a Map. This would avoid to go through the `newList` at every iteration.

Comment: @sagar I added a better way on my answer, nicer and more optimised. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Group the students by their `idNumber` as

```
Map<String, List<Student>> idNumberToStudentsMap = students
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getIdNumber));
```

Now, the `idNumberToStudentsMap` has all the students with the same `idNumber` grouped (as a list) in one map entry. So, to satisy your requirement all the students in each entry must be assigned the same rollNumber.

Assign the rollNumber as

```
AtomicInteger rollNumberProvider = new AtomicInteger(0);
idNumberToStudentsMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        String currentRollNumber = String.valueOf(rollNumberProvider.incrementAndGet());
        value.forEach(student -> student.setRollNumber(currentRollNumber));
    });
```

where `currentRollNumber` is the roll number to be assigned to *all* the students with a particular `idNumber`.

---

Java 7 version of the same

```
Map<String, List<Student>> idNumberToStudentsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Student student : students) {
    if (!idNumberToStudentsMap.containsKey(student.getIdNumber())) {
        idNumberToStudentsMap.put(student.getIdNumber(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    idNumberToStudentsMap.get(student.getIdNumber()).add(student);
}
AtomicInteger rollNumberProvider = new AtomicInteger(0);

for(Map.Entry<String, List<Student>> entry : idNumberToStudentsMap.entrySet()) {
    String currentRollNumber = String.valueOf(rollNumberProvider.incrementAndGet());
    //All these students have the same idNumber
    List<Student> studentsWithSameId = entry.getValue();
    for (Student student : studentsWithSameId) {
        student.setRollNumber(currentRollNumber);
    }
}
```